# How to ensure text appears on top of other UI elements?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I hope make text that always visible in screen, see my gif
[image]

I hope text in FloatingTextCanvs visible but it's covered by button, I find the later create ui object will cover previous objects, can i change text object's index to make text always visible?

Comment: You want to set your text in front of all other UIs. Did I understand correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display one canvas in front of the other, you want to change the `Sort Order` property on the `Canvas` component to be higher than the other canvas.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with two separate canvases then you can set their sort order to determine which one appears on top.

[image]

If you are dealing with two UI elements that are children of the same canvas, then their physical arrangement within the hierarchy determines which one appears on top. The child at the top of the hierarchy will appear underneath the other elements. For example, in the following MainMenuCanvas, the Background image will appear behind the Text.

[image]